# In Which language Upanishads are written - Classical Sanskrit or Vedic Sanskrit?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, sanskrit

I want to know in which language Upanishads are written ? - Defunct Vedic Sanskrit or Normal Classical Sanskrit .

I am asking this as Vedic sanskrit is defunct language , so it has not been 100 percent accurately deciphered yet ( eg - there are multiple translation of gayatri mantra)

Comment: Classical Sanskrit was documented by Panini out of Vedic Sanskrit. Classical Sanskrit contains a little amount of Dravidian influence not found in Vedic Sanskrit.

Comment: Vedic Sanskrit is the language in which the Vaidika knowledge has been revealed.

Comment: brahmi script, Vedic Sanskrit